How to remove negation from japanese sentence and extract keywords (tfidf search )?
I want to remove negation from user query and extarct keywords from it for a search engine, for example .
`NISAを除いてリストを見せ
English translation : Show me the list excluding NISA
For this I don't want nisa as a keyword as user is excluding it.
I am using tfidf for keyword search .I am not able to handle negation in user sentences.
I tried using llm to manipulate my query but is not giving proper result below is the prompt I am using.
[
{"role": "system", "content": "Analyze user query and return only relevant keywords from it in . Give answer in this format 'keyword, keyword, keyword'. Give keywords in same language as the user query. Skip verbs like show, display. Also change the keywords to lowercase if they are in english language. Whenever query mentions 'not nisa' , 'excluding nisa' for this keyword would be 'tsumitate'. If a keyword is preceded by negation then don't return that keyword.Keep the tense of the keywords as it is. Do not skip any keyword"}, 
{{#session}}
{{^last}}
{"role":"{{{role}}}", "content":"{{{content}}}"},
{{/last}}
{{#last}}
{"role":"{{{role}}}", "content":" user query : '{{content}} ' "}
{{/last}}
{{/session}}
]




Model I am using : gpt35-turbo chat model

The verb 除いて translates literally as except. I'd have thought most LLM would handle that. In Japanese negation can be tricky since it often happens at the end of a sentence. A real headache for real time human translators on the bilingual news. Encouraging users to use + and - on search terms might be one way out.


and - on search terms meaning we can suggest  users to add terms like for not nisa i want tsumitate

like that you are saying ?
